# Can't seem to get rid of new white space lines in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, dom

EDIT:

For those having issues with mysql data that won't get rid of white spaces between rows. It's because of deep tabbed indents due to an issue when copy pasting from editors/word documents.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49611

Here is the bug that doesn't allow me to fix this issue, it's because of deep indents, it's a MYSQL bug that won't be fixed.

PS: Message to community, Thanks to the guys that downvoted this question without giving time to properly formulate the issue. It's a debug process, you can let people know if you need something instead of acting rude and attacking the questioner, after all as the poster I'm likely to read and see what you need. If I knew what was needed to diagnose the issue, I would've found it and would not be posting here. Since I posted here, it means I don't know where to look as to identify if the issue is a MYSQL one or a PHP one. Be polite with your community guys, don't act like wolves trying to bite someone's head off all the time because they didn't give you everything you wanted right off the bat.. Take care.

---

Here is the raw paste from the database:

```
    one two three











one two three





one two three





one two three





one two three
```

Why is it still being like this? I str_replaced  's and \n\n\n's . I don't want to get rid of 2 \n's due to the format of the text I need in between the text.

The result I'm looking for is :

```
 one two three

 one two three

 one two three
 one two three
```

Meaning max 2 \n's.

Comment: And your questions is _Why is it still being like this_? Put some effort in constructing the question. What have you done, what's your code so far?

Comment: Where's the code?  Where is the database contents?  Where is any sign that you're trying to help people who want to help you?

Comment: It's a raw paste of the data form mysql... there is no code.

Comment: @Darius you need to post the code that inserts the text into the database

Comment: _The measures most would use_ cannot be of any help to anyone trying to **help you**.

Comment: The only code I have for you is str_replace("&nbsp;","",$textfromdb); and str_replace("\n\n",$textfromdb); and that didn't solve it.

Comment: @VladBalmos kk, one sec.

Comment: `str_replace` takes three parameters, not two. Add the proper code to your question.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević dude... only the 2nd one has a typo as I typed it in a haste..

Comment: @Darius you are being rude and unhelpfull. You have to post the code in the question so we can see it better. i'm flagging this question

Comment: @VladBalmos You guys started going control/power mad and full on attack mode because I didn't realize what was needed. I thought raw copy paste was enough, was in the process of getting the insert data for you. Np. Flag it, delete the question. Take care.

Comment: And if anyone's interested, it's because I ran into this MYSQL bug. 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```
$normalized = preg_replace('~(\r?\n\r?){3+}~', "\n\n", $original);
```

But hey, it's hard to say. You want to keep stack overflow a happy place, you put some effort to posting a question.

Comment: Honestly, didn't know how else to formulate this question.. My apologies... The raw paste data is somewhat private. Will try this. thank you.